# In Windows, where can I find the PhP directory?

Tags: php, windows

I did this code:

```
$privKey = openssl_pkey_new();  
    //define(INITIALCODE, "hello.com");
    $hello = openssl_error_string() ;
    $timenow=time();
```

The content of $hello is 
error:02001003:system library:fopen:No such process

So I search for solution and it says that I have to add PhP directory to path:

```
Go to Control Panel and open the System icon (Start -> Settings -> Control Panel -> System, or just Start -> Control Panel -> System for Windows XP/2003)
Go to the Advanced tab
Click on the ‘Environment Variables’ button
Look into the ‘System Variables’ pane
Find the Path entry (you may need to scroll to find it)
Double click on the Path entry
Enter your PHP directory ant the end, including ‘;’ before (e.g. ;C:\php)
Press OK and restart your computer
```

The problem is what is PHP directory and where can I find it? Is it in phpmyinfo? What?

Comment: How did you install PHP? PHP does not come with Windows.

Comment: I install it using zend server. Actually what is PHP directory anyway? Is it the directory that contain php.exe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Search for `php.exe`. The directory it's in should be added to your path variable.